# Do I need a bleeder resistor for discharging an inductor?

Tags: circuit-design, inductor, safety, thermal

Pretty straightforward question, I'd say.

I know that for a capacitor I'd definitely want a bleeding/discharge resistor, and I know how to size one for that ([cheat sheet for anyone curious](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Capacitor-discharge-calculator.php#answer)), but what about inductors?

It's not like the magnetic field of an inductor will stay there the way charge does on an inductor. Will it dissipate into eddy currents/heat?

Comment: You may be asking about something called an RC snubber.

Answer (score 5):

The answer isn't as straightforward as it first appears since the equivalent of a capacitor left open is an inductor that is *short-circuited*.  Leaving an inductor suddenly *open* is the "catastrophic failure mode" equivalent to short-circuiting a capacitor, resulting in very high voltage across the inductor (corresponding to very high current from the capacitor).

A superconducting inductor that is short-circuited will just keep the current running like a well-isolated capacitor will keep the voltage stable when left open.

To use up the energy, you need to dissipate it.  A flyback diode does dissipate some energy due to its forward voltage drop but will, with real inductors, dissipate most energy in the inductor's ohmic resistance itself: most inductors are not superconducting.  If you need faster dissipation, you'll use a larger drop-off voltage via a Zener diode or multiple flyback diodes in series or by adding a resistor.

Comment: Have a look at this paper about quenching superconducting magnets https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3927.pdf

Comment: @DDuck Well, that kind of thermal runaway is reminiscent of secondary breakdown in power transistors, except that in superconductors it's the increase in resistance where the heat focuses and causes the catastrophe while in the transistor it is the decrease in resistance.

Answer (score 2):

> *It's not like the magnetic field of an inductor will stay there the
> way charge does on an inductor. Will it dissipate into eddy
> currents/heat?*

The moment you open circuit an inductor carrying current, the magnetic field will dissipate and, it dissipates by producing a spark unless you have some discharge circuit. Even then, the discharge circuit has to be designed so that it still doesn't generate a voltage that is too high for any circuits associated with that inductor.

This can be

- a parallel resistor,
- a parallel capacitor,
- a flyback diode,
- a snubber,
- a Zener diode arrangement or
- a diode clamp circuit.

The choice is dependent on the associated circuit and functionality.

An decent inductor will not produce much heat as eddy currents because, inductors are usually designed not to have significant eddy current losses.